# Is there any way to increase the width of the autocomplete box in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, xcode9

Is there any way to increase the width of the autocomplete box in Xcode?

I run Xcode on a Widescreen Monitor, and it is a waste of screen space to not use it. I know I can just type whatever to make the specific function or property appear, but I wouldn't mind just seeing the function as well.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Nope :( I don't have time to deeply investigate, but I would love a way to do this! I hate seeing 5 identical functions and wandering which I need to use. The other thing is that when you make custom functions replicating many of these in custom classes, they almost have to be wordier make the issue exaggerated further.

Comment: I know, how cool would it be to have a autosize option on the window, even as simple as auto/ draw in view section of Xcode. Definitely agree with you when you write custom methods or blocks and completion. I guess I’ll work on making my methods shorter:):):) I’ll update if any;) thanks.